# How can I change the default IDetailPane in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin that creates an alternative `IDetailPane` for the debugger.

I created an implementation of `IDetailPaneFactory` that returns my `IDetailPane`'s ID and it's `.getDetailPaneTypes(...)` method gets called.

However, now the field `DetailPaneManager.fPreferredDetailPanes` is a `Map<Set<String>, String>` with the content:

```
{
  [DefaultDetailPane]=DefaultDetailPane
  [DefaultDetailPane, MyDetailPane]=DefaultDetailPane
}
```

I want to change the 2nd item so that it'll map to "MyDetailPane" instead.

Is this a user setting that I can change somewhere in the settings? (tried finding it in the preferences but didn't see anything relevant). Is this hard coded somewhere? Can I change something in my plugin's `Activator` to control this? (tried changing the value during my `Activator.start(...)`, but at this point `fPreferredDetailPanes` doesn't contain the 2nd item in the map)

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but could you share your solution? I'm facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `chooseDetailsAreaIDInSet` method in `DetailPaneManager` chooses the preferred pane by iterating through the detail pane factories calling `getDefaultDetailPane(selection)`, the first factory to return a id from this wins.

The `AvailableDetailPanesAction.SetDetailPaneAction` menu action can override this with the user's choice.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to automatically set this with the installation of my plugin, but AvailableDetailPanesAction.SetDetailPaneAction pointed me to a solution that was good enough for my needs. Thanks!